# Logging all request and response in Spring Boot REST service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I use `Spring boot` and have some `REST` controllers. I want to logging all request and response. I using external tomacat, not embeded! I write `Interceptor`:

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class LoggingWebMvcInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        final ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        log.debug("REQ!!!! {}", wrapper.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        //log.debug("Response: {}", response);
    }
```

And adding his:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final LoggingWebMvcInterceptor loggingWebMvcInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public WebMvcConfig(LoggingWebMvcInterceptor loggingWebMvcInterceptor) {
        this.loggingWebMvcInterceptor = loggingWebMvcInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(loggingWebMvcInterceptor);
    }
}
```

But It don't work!

When I try `POST` request, his logging, but I have error: `"Required request body is missing`.

What am I doing wrong? I created a wrapper for the request! 
I need to completely log all requests (POST, GET, DELETE, PUT) with headers and body and all responses. How can i do this? Any help, please.

Comment: can you please post your controller class!

Comment: Please include the request data that you're sending, and indicate whether you are asking for assistance with the logging interceptor not working, or the post request not working

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem is not every well understood (not documented well -- for example where this is coming from is not shown `Required request body is missing.`) but anyways.

For logging purposes, I would not go with an `Interceptor` as I feel that this is too much work. Instead you could very well create an Aspect with a pointcut defined to around methods annotated with the various Spring controller annotation. The `ProceedingJoinPoint`#`proceed` method effectively allows you to grab the response object and the request itself contains all the information needed regarding parameters, IP, methods and so on.

With that in hand, you could then inject a HttpServletRequest in there, thus ending up having all the right tools to perform any logging activities.

Adding the caching wrapper is something very correct indeed if you would like to cache and re-read the HttpServletRequest's body multiple time but I would avoid adding it in the `Interceptor`/`Aspect` itself.

Comment: Can you give some example on this? I just want to log requests and responses from my service, I did not think it was so difficult

Comment: @All_Safe well it's not, albeit that the Aspect approach may require you to add some extra code to render the response into a loggable string. Other than that,all the rest are pretty straightforward. A simple search for logging aspects will turn up quite a few results.

Answer (score 0):

According to Baeldung documentation, ContentCachingRequestWrapper class has these limitations:

> ContentCachingRequestWrapper class only supports the following:
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Method-Type:POST

and

> We must invoke the following method to ensure that request data is cached in ContentCachingRequestWrapper before using it: `requestCacheWrapperObject.getParameterMap();`

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

Answer (score -2):

You can use a web Filter (javax.servlet.Filter) as :

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain){
//Log actions heres
chain.doFilter(req, resp);}}
```

Then declare your filter in web.xml as :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>package.CustomFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```